# AWS update kinesis firehose configuration pro-grammatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Currently I am writing a test library to test the configuration settings. I would like to set only few parameters of firehose like SizeInMBs and IntervalInSeconds. All other parameters will remain same. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following method

`def set_firehose_buffering_hints(self, size_mb, interval_sec):
        response = self._firehose_client.describe_delivery_stream(DeliveryStreamName=self.firehose)
        lambdaarn = (response['DeliveryStreamDescription']
                        ['Destinations'][0]['ExtendedS3DestinationDescription']
                        ['ProcessingConfiguration']['Processors'][0]['Parameters'][0]['ParameterValue'])
        response = self._firehose_client.update_destination(DeliveryStreamName=self.firehose,
            CurrentDeliveryStreamVersionId=response['DeliveryStreamDescription']['VersionId'],
            DestinationId=response['DeliveryStreamDescription']['Destinations'][0]['DestinationId'],
            ExtendedS3DestinationUpdate={
                            "BufferingHints": {
                                "IntervalInSeconds": interval_sec,
                                "SizeInMBs": size_mb
                            },
                            'ProcessingConfiguration': {
                            'Processors': [{
                                            'Type': 'Lambda',
                                            'Parameters': [
                                            {
                                                'ParameterName': 'LambdaArn',
                                                'ParameterValue': lambdaarn
                                            },
                                            { 
                                                'ParameterName': 'BufferIntervalInSeconds',
                                                'ParameterValue': str(interval_sec)
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'ParameterName': 'BufferSizeInMBs',
                                                'ParameterValue': str(size_mb)
                                            }]
                            }]
                            }})`